# Can this stud group be sistered?

Tags: repair, studs, dry-rot

This is a partially rotten stud group of an exterior staircase wall (only 1/5 of total height is shown), it's not load bearing (it just holds the siding, plywood and flashing of parapet wall). Can this stud group be sistered somehow?

Update: Added location of stud group.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Where do you propose new studs be added? Isn't that a doorway or something? Also, please revise to add context. The situation overall isn't apparent.

Comment: That is a lot of wood just to hold siding/plywood.  Usually that amount is only used for load bearing.   Unless they just kept adding wood when the original pieces rotted out.

Comment: if it bears no load, why did they put 5 studs in there?

Answer (score 4):

That section looks too bad to sister. You'd want to remove that section up to the good wood and replace it with similar planks (they don't look like 2x4's) or some larger lumber.

Comment: If one is going to cut out supports, ensure there's enough temporary support nearby that floors/ceiling above don't collapse. Sure, it's not likely if the repairs only take an hour or two, but let's be honest, pros might get this replaced in an hour or two. A skilled homeowner doing DIY will be well prepared ahead of time but could take half a day or more. An unskilled homeowner doing this type of work for the first time could take several days.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @JACK and would recommend bringing an engineer in to tell you how to support it properly while rebuilding and what to replace it with.

And it might be worth hiring a contractor to deal with it rather than DIY for several reasons. First, they will know where too look for other problems that may interact badly with this one. Second, they are insured so if something major does go wrong you aren't covering all the costs of recovering, assuming recovery is possible.

Someone in my neighborhood had two problems with their house which combined to make repairing either one more risky than any contractor was willing to touch. They would up replacing the whole building. You probably want to know if you are courting disaster, and how to minimize the risk if so, before you start.